# Can I pass different parameter instead of (n1,n2,n3)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Write a function called `sumArray` which accepts a single argument: an array of numbers. It should return the sum of all the numbers in the array.

Condition:

1. You will need a variable to keep track of total. It should start out as zero.
2. Loop over the array for each element, add it to total variable.

```js
function sumArray(n1, n2, n3) {
  let total = n1 + n2 + n3;
  return total;
}

sumArray([3,45,66]);
```

Comment: If it asks to get the sum of array. Just send the array to function and return sum of total items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop from array and get the output

```js
function sumArray(arr){
  let total = 0;
  arr.forEach((i) => total+=i);
  return total;
}
console.log(sumArray([3,45,66]));
```

Or you can try with reduce as explained by Cristian

```js
function sumArray(arr){
  const reducer = (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue;
  let total = arr.reduce(reducer)
  return total;
}
console.log(sumArray([3,45,66]));
```

Comment: There are cases where using outer scope variables from within a callback is needed, but it's generally considered bad practice since it breaks the functional pattern. I think a better example would involve using `reduce`

Comment: @CristianTraìna Your right but i forget to put the reduce example in it.